# array of deferred ajax requests never entering in when.apply().done()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

I have the following code to handle several ajax requests, and wait for them all to proccess and combine their result insite `when.apply`:

```
var requestsArray = [];

var url = "http://...";

console.log("url: " + url);

var req1 = $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    dataType : "xml"
});

req1.done(function (resp1) {
    $(resp1).find('interest').each(function() {

        var interest_id = $(this).find('id').text();
        var interest_name = $(this).find('name').text();

        var request = $.ajax({
              type:"GET",
              URL: "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&page="+ interest_name + "&redirects&prop=text",
              dataType: "jsonp"
        });
        requestsArray.push(request);

    });

    $.when.apply(null, requestsArray).done(function () {
        console.log(arguments);
         // You can collect the responses in the same order from `arguments`
        var responses = arguments;
    });

});
```

why it is never entering in the `$.when.apply`, and it doesnt print any `console.log(arguments);` ?

Comment: At first view , not appear `arguments` within `.done()` callback , i.e.g., `.done(function(data) {}) // data : arguments` for `console.log(arguments)`

Comment: that wasnt the problem still didn't entered

Comment: You will need to do your own debugging.  Check the browser error log for script errors.  Set error handlers for your ajax calls and promises to see if any are returning errors.  Set several breakpoints (or insert `console.log()` statements) and see how far it is getting before it stops.  This is basic debugging to find out where it stops or why it stops.

Comment: any advice on where to start?

Comment: @João: Are you saying it never calls `$.when`, or are you saying it never enters the callback in which you log the arguments?

Comment: it never enters in this part of the code:  $.when.apply(null, requestsArray).done(function () {
        console.log(arguments);
         // You can collect the responses in the same order from `arguments`
        var responses = arguments;
    });

Comment: @João - what do you  mean advice on where to start?  I gave you a list of things to do to debug this yourself in my previous comment.  You should do all of them and find out what you learn.  You will likely find one or more errors in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    URL: "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&page=" + 
//  ^^^
         interest_name + "&redirects&prop=text",
    dataType: "jsonp"
});
```

You've misspelled the [`$.ajax` parameter](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). It needs to be `url`, not `URL`.

With no `url` given, it will fetch the current page, which is not in jsonp format, which will lead to a parseerror, which fill not call your `done` callback but the [`fail` callback](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/) which you didn't pass.

Comment: Got errors with wikimedia url , either `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : ` - though data at url appear to be valid json when navigate to that document ; or `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` issue . Tried piece at console , jsfiddle ? Workarounds ; issue in mediawiki url query string ? Thanks